# How to start a bound service via intent without class

Tags: android, service

I'm trying to start a bound (eventually remote) Android Service via an `Intent`.  If I create the `Intent` with a reference to the `Service` class (see variable ii below) it works.  If I create the `Intent` using Strings for the classname, `bindService` fails.

Ultimately I'm aiming to have a 2nd application access my service which will not have the `Service` class within it (that's how remote service things work...? isn't it?) - hence the desire to create the `Intent` without the reference to the class object.

```
        //this Intent works
        Intent ii = new Intent(this, MyService.class);

        //this Intent doesn't
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClassName("com.ghee", "MyService");

        boolean b = bindService(ii,
                mSvcConn,
                Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        if(!b) {
            Log.d(TAG, "bindService returned false...");
        }
```

If it helps, here's the majority of the manifest:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon">
  <activity android:name=".MyActivity" 
              android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <action android:name="com.ghee.MyService" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>

  <service android:name=".MyService"
         android:exported="true" 
         android:process=":remote">
  </service>
</application>
```

Comment: try Intent.setClassName(Context packageContext, String className) and you will see where you failed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the full path of the class, not just its name. This seems counter-intuitive, because you're already specifying the package in parameter 1, but....oh well.

Try this:

```
i.setClassName("com.ghee", "com.ghee.MyService");
```